# Proper database structure for storing orders which contain products with different attributes

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've been trying to come up with a solution for my problem for several days now, but without luck. I was hoping someone might be able to help me. I'm sorry if the description is too long.

I would like to build a website where customers can choose out of these products and can order any combination of them.

### Product A:

Fully customized product (I will verbosely describe the customization process even if not all information may be important for table structure)

Customer can assemble product out of a list of components and:

1. There are two types of components - main component and supplementary component
2. Each component has a specific weight and price
3. Main component consists of supplementary components, BUT they have different weights than when listed solo (important for tracking how much of which component was sold)
4. Each product has to contain exactly 1 main component and can contain 0 to many supplementary components
5. Total weight of supplementary components is always <= weight of the main component
6. Final weight of main component is calculated as "original main component's weight - total weight of supplementary components)

Eg.

add Main component MC (weight 1000g)
add Sup. component 1 (weight 100g)
add Sup. component 2 (weight 200g)

Final product consists of:
Main component MC 700g
Sup. component 1  100g
Sup. component 2  200g

Each product has unique code (reason explained later).

### Product B:

Products, which are pre-assembled and made for direct purchase (made out of components, but again components can have different weights than when listed solo in assembly module)

### Product C:

Other items, unrelated to components - T-shirts, Mugs

**My question is - what would be the most effecient database structure for storing orders of these items** when:

1. I need to display all order items for a specific order and when there's Product A present, list all of it's components and components of the main component
2. I need to be able to reconstruct already bought customized product (Product A) by code and remove individual components if they're no longer in stock/available
3. Weights and prices of all components can change in time + components of main components and Product Bs can change too
4. I need to be able to track how much of each component was sold and when

I have the following DB structure so far, but I don't think I'm on the right track:

**components**

- id (PK)
- name
- price
- weight

**orders** (not relevant columns like number, customer_firstname, delivery_method etc. omitted)

- id (PK)

**order_items** (fields common to all product types)

- id (PK)
- order_id (FK to orders.id)
- code
- name
- price
- quantity

**order_producta**

- id (PK)
- order_item_id (FK to order_items.id)
- component_id (FK to components.id)
- quantity
- price
- weight

Thank you very much in advance for your reply. If I explained something unclearly, I will gladly edit my question with additional info.

Comment: Why is mass difference "important for tracking how much of which component was sold"? Please clarify how exactly is the mass used. Are components discrete (like mechanical parts) or "splittable" (like some fluid)? Perhaps describe the actual real-life problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Is possible for the same component to act as a "main component" in one product and "supplementary" in another?

Comment: _BTW, "mass" and "weight" are different things. Mass is amount of matter, does not change with changes in gravity and is measured in kilograms, while weight is a force exerted in given gravity field and (as any force) is measured in newtons._